# PHP Variable from Separate file jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Im trying to grab a variable from a separate php file into a jQuery `if` statement (I'm just basically wondering how I can import a php file into jQuery)

(**The script is to count the characters in a `textarea`**)

Current Code:

```
$( document.body ).ready(function() {
    $('#message-input').live('keyup',function(){
        if ($message == 0) {
            $('#message-count').html('Enter at least 14 characters');
        }

        var count = ($(this).val().length);
        if ($message < 20 && $message > 1) {
            $('#message-count').html('Enter atleast more ' + count + ' characters');
        }

        var remaining = 1000 - ($(this).val().length);
        if ($message > 20) {
            $('#message-count').html(remaining +' more characters to go');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: And what's your question?  What isn't working?  What does `"put a variable from a separate php file"` even mean?  Where are you trying to actually do that?  (Note: There's no PHP code here.)

Comment: I'm trying to grab a variable and put it into a `if` statement. Import or include a variable (Or import a php file)

Comment: So are you asking how to include a PHP file?  (`include("someFile.php")`)  How to write a variable to the page?  (`<?php echo $someVariable; ?>`)

Comment: My php file has a variable ( `$message` ) I need to get that variable into a jQuery `if` statement

Comment: So then that would be `<?php echo $message; ?>` where you want it to be output to the page.  To be honest, it really sounds like what you're looking for is an introductory tutorial on PHP.  Outputting a value to the page will be covered by *any* tutorial.

Comment: i think you have $message = 20 (some limit number) . you want use it in js to limit the text count is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `jQuery` codes are written inside a `PHP` file, you can do this

```
// inside yourfile.php

// Pass your php var into a js var
var message = <?php echo $message ?>;

// You can now use var message here...
$( document.body ).ready(function() {
    $('#message-input').live('keyup',function(){
        // if ($message == 0) {
        if (message == 0) {
            $('#message-count').html('Enter at least 14 characters');
        }

        var count = ($(this).val().length);
        // if ($message < 20 && $message > 1) {
        if (message < 20 && message > 1) {
            $('#message-count').html('Enter atleast more ' + count + ' characters');
        }

        var remaining = 1000 - ($(this).val().length);
        // if ($message > 20) {
        if (message > 20) {
            $('#message-count').html(remaining +' more characters to go');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If the script is separate from the jQuery Page you can just use AJAX. Have your PHP output it as JSON.

```
    $.getJSON( "yourPHPScript.php", function( data ) {
      //data is whatever the PHP returned
      console.log( "JSON Data: "+data );
     });
```

if its just raw, you will need to parse it.

Comment: why the down vote, this is the only way to "import" an PHP file into a jQuery Script.

Comment: Correct, but reading the comments, it seems that what the OP actually wants is to pass a PHP variable (not an entire PHP file) to jQuery so he can use it in his `if` statement. He fails to clearly state it in his question, though. PS: I'm not the one who downvoted.